# Custom profile with all permissions and NO access to data

Tags: permissions, custom-profile, record-access-level

I need to setup a user profile with access to all configuration settings (object manager, change sets, development, etc.) but **NO** access to production data (NONE).

Can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would suggest to you start reading this documentation from Salesforce about who sees what -> https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_data_access.htm&type=5

We need more information to help you, like about security -> Organization-Wide Defaults, if everything is private and the profile you set doesn't have access to modify all, you should be fine, but as I said I recommend you read the article because there could have sharing settings or groups which you should avoid on that particular user/profile

Start with minium access profile from salesforce, from there you'll have a great start point.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will surely read it. The customer request is quite straightforward: they want the consulting partner to be able to configure (have access to object manager, implement change sets, develop, flows, etc.), but their security team needs external users to have access to NO data at all... Sounds like a tricky request.

Comment: hmm as far as I'm concerned is a normal request from clients which has a lot of sensitive data.

Comment: I see the documentation refers to data access, which is fine. The problem is when the user tries to DELETE a custom field, that user needs the "view all data" permission...

Comment: Is really necessary to delete fields?
I mean if they request that you should say to them to do that, because it is a limitation from Salesforce, Or use Session-Based Permission Set to you only have that access when it is necessary for deleting

Comment: Well yes, that's the request. The external admin should be able to perform a number of configuration/setup tasks providing that user has no access to data...

Comment: ok so, the external admin will be able to do that, just the delete option won't be able to perform, if the client is really requesting it, I do recommend opening a Salesforce Ticket under their production org to ask a such a thing,

Why deleting is really necessary to have to see all? because when you delete a field your user should see the record to remove the information about that field, so on my perspective on how Salesforce handles that is not possible in a standard way to perform deletions without  that permission

Comment: Thank you Elivelton. We could use your suggestions and we're doing fine so far. Deleting fields can be notified to the System administrator if needed.